# WCF аутентификация

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

Всем привет.

**Есть:**

- WCF сервис на NET 4.5.2 со стандартной базовой аутентификацией по средством передачи логина и пароля.
- для обеспечения шифрования данных между клиентом и сервером используется SSL сертификат.
- сервис развернут на IIS.

**Проблема:**

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что с данным сервисом ни как не хочет работать клиент (генерируется средствами Visual Studio) написанный на NET 2.0 (использование является обязательным). Летит исключение: "***SoapHeaderException:*** *Ошибка при проверке безопасности сообщения*".

Путем экспериментов выяснилось, что если на стороне серверной части отключить аутентификацию (т.е. чтобы сервис **НЕ** запрашивал логин и пароль) и попробовать обратиться к сервису проблем не будет - все работает на ура. Проблемы возникают только когда включена аутентификация.

Что-то вразумительного, как решить эту проблему и заставить работать клиента так и не нашел. Ваши мысли, господа? )

P.S. При **включенной аутентификации** с данным сервисом отлично работает клиент написанный на NET 3.0.

Comment: SOAP — экскременты мамонта, нынче в моде REST. .NET 2.0 — экскременты мамонта, поддержка Microsoft для которых закончилась 4 года назад. Стандартизированность, кросс-платформенность и остальные плюсы SOAP — фикция и пыль в глаза. Это так, общая картина. А теперь к деталям. Поддержка .NET 3.5 SP1 протухла совсем недавно, на момент выхода .NET 4.5 поддерживалась, поэтому с этой точки можно рассчитывать хоть на что-то. Ну а если хочется .NET 2.0 — шаманить, например (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11263640 — пример шаманства).